# Why doesnt ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES work as expected?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, privileges

I have 2 users. User1 is writing and member of the role writing, while User2 is member of the role "reader".

The reader role received subsequent permissions:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE to reader
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA x TO reader
```

I want the reader to be able to read/select all existing and new tables from the given schema but using

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA x GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO reader;
```

does't work. User2 won't receive any permission for new tables created by User1/the writer role.

Using:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE writer IN SCHEMA x GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO reader;
```

doesn't work either. I have to explitly name the Owner of that table. To solve this I had to use:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE User1 IN SCHEMA x GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO reader;
```

which I actually don't want, because there may be other users than User1 who are going to publish tables into that schema as well.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: There was a [similar question](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20181114190815.72lprnsyh4w7c67c%40riseup.net) on pgsql-general recently. In short, it would be difficult to implement that safely.

Comment: So I just have to accept that I have to explitly name relevant table owners for that given scheme? There is no other best practice?

Comment: The best practice is to have a very limited number of users who can create tables in a certain schema. Then it doesn't hurt to run `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` for all of them.

Comment: > "Then it doesn't hurt to run ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for all".

I disagree. Separating Users (who) from Roles (what they can do) seems a sound practice, that is not really possible in Postgres because og this limitation. Users (concrete people, services) come and go over time, but roles (like admin or reader) could be mostly static.

Comment: @AdamAL And you think that allowing users that come and go to create tables with their login role is sound practice?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe To me it is. If I assign a user to a role which is allowed to create tables in a specific schema, all readers who are allowed to read tables created by that role, should be able to read them, independently from the fact who in detail created them. 
At the moment I'm struggling again with this issue and the fact it doesn't work like described. It doesn't make any sense to me at all. If I design a user group and have users who are inheriting their permissions (developers), I can't see why a group of readers have to get matched to each individual developer instead of their group.

Comment: It might not be what you want, but it works as described (I patched the description recently). I don't see why it is a problem to run an `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement for each role right after you `CREATE` it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Ok. thanks for clarification. Got it now. It isn't a problem directly. To me, it just feels like it's not matching the general concept. If I have two group roles which complement each other, and I add users to those groups, it feels unnatural to me to care for individual user settings on top. I also still don't see the advantage why I would or should want that, if I explicitly configure group roles which are meant to take care for it. I might have missed something, but the documentation isn't clear on this point.